# How to remove the html when listing content like in a archive page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to strip the html when I am displaying a list of content with a short blurb.

How can I do this?

Right now it is displaying the tags, not what the tags render, but the actual tags like:

```
this is a article about <b>cars</b>
```

The content is safe as its done by all internal folk who can be trusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strip_tags` can be the method you are looking for.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags

Answer (score 0):

You're probably escaping your HTML before you render it to the page.  If you insert your content with

```
<%=h content %>
```

change it to

```
<%= content %>
```

or, if you use the safe_erb plugin

```
<%= content.untaint %>
```

and you should be fine.

Or if you just want to strip all the tags (you'll lose any inline formatting), something like

```
<%=h content.gsub(/<[^>]*>/, '') %>
```

should do the trick.

Hope that helps!